# "benutzen" or "nutzen" for using the toilet

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

> "Dürfte ich Ihre Toilette ***_*__**?"
>
> a) benutzen
>
> b) nutzen

Since we're using an object (the toilet), "benutzen" should work. But does "nutzen" work or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both are possible and understandable, but `benutzen` is more common. (`Toilette benutzen` has 40000 hits on google, `Toilette nutzen` only 10000)